# ReSharper File Layout - Sorting Conversion Operators Separately from Other Operators

Tags: resharper, stylecop

I'm forced to comply with StyleCop rule 1201.  StyleCopAnalyzers is stating that conversion operators must appear before other operators.  I use ReSharper code cleanup to organize the files which has worked great until I needed to define operator + and a conversion operator for the same class.

How can I get ReSharper file layout to differentiate between conversion operators and other operators so that I may have them sorted according to StyleCop?

[edit]
I will also accept a way to change the ordering rule for StyleCop.Analyzers, but according to [issue 2541](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/2541) there doesn't appear to be a way currently.

Comment: Hmm, I recently [wrote a blog post](https://collinmbarrett.com/stylecop-ordering-resharper/) that could be helpful. However, I didn't see anything about operators in [rule 1201](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1201.md), so I didn't capture the rule you are trying to implement. Where are you getting that operators should be sorted with conversions first in 1201?

Comment: @collin, Although the [documentation](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1201.md) for StyleCop.Analyzers rule 1201 doesn't state anything about operators, the code for [`TypeMemberOrder`](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/OrderingRules/SA1201ElementsMustAppearInTheCorrectOrder.cs#L134) clearly places conversion operators before other operators.